# A link to the server could not be established Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

HI guys im having issues connecting to my Database `Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'peace4love'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/peace4love/public_html/ivegotdiamonds.com/wp-content/plugins/hsquare/config-new.php on line 14

Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/peace4love/public_html/ivegotdiamonds.com/wp-content/plugins/hsquare/config-new.php on line 14
Error, query failed`  here is the code:

```
<?php
require_once(ABSPATH."/lib/myplug.php");
$objMem = new myPlug();

$table_name = "h_config";
$addme=@$_POST["addme"];
global $wpdb;

$act=$_REQUEST["act"];
if($act=="upd")
{
    $recid=$_REQUEST["id"];
    $sSQL="select * from ".$table_name." where config_id=$recid";
    $result = mysql_query($sSQL) or die ('Error, query failed');
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 )
    {
        if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $id = $row['config_id'];
            $c_key  = $row['c_key'];
            $c_value = $row['c_value'];
            $c_index = $row['c_index'];
            $c_record = $row['c_record'];
            $c_record_2 = $row['c_record_2'];
            $c_record_3 = $row['c_record_3'];
            $c_record_4 = $row['c_record_4'];
            $btn       = "Update Record";
            $hidval    = 32;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    $btn ="Add New Record";
    $c_key  = "";
    $c_value = "";
    $c_index = "";
    $c_record = "";
    $c_record_2 = "";
    $c_record_3 = "";
    $c_record_4 = "";
    $btn = "Add New Record";
    $hidval    = 31;
}
```

?>

Comment: If I need to guess I would say you didn't configured user access to the database for user peace4love from localhost.

Comment: I'm missing a `mysql_connect` anywhere in the code, is it called elsewhere?

Comment: Thats a database for a different website.

Comment: it is not called anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**

The mysql API (all mysql_* functions) is deprecated and will be removed from PHP. You should consider switching to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php):
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

**Answer**

You need to call [mysql_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) to connect to your database server before calling [mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). It opens a connection to your MySQL server with the parameters you provided to it: host, port, username, password.

You also need to select the db you are using with the [mysql_select_db()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php) function.

Example from PHP documentation, trying to connect to database `foo` on the server `localhost` on port `3306` (default MySQL port) with `mysql_user` login and `mysql_password` password:

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('localhost:3306', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('foo', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}

?>
```

You can then use the mysql_query() function.